# javascript to achive the same result as css ellipsis

Tags: javascript, jquery

due to some reason I cant use the css method

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100px;
```

the above make my user define text in a li if reached 100px, it will add '...', can it be achieve using jquery?

Comment: Ridiculous number of plugins can be found online... https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+ellipsis&oq=jquery+elli&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.3600j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [Jquery ellipse plugin](https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/jquery-ellipsis)

```
$('#target').ellipsis({
    row: 2
});
```